# How to select rows except a certain one out of table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

```
$("#experiences tr").gt(0).dblclick(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

I used the above code to exclude the first row,

but it turned out to be wrong.

double click on all rows has no response now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#experiences tr:gt(0)").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

or

```
$("#experiences tr:not(:first)").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

exclude just the second row:

```
$("#experiences tr:not(:eq(1))").dblclick(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: What if I want to exclude the 2nd row?

Comment: why isn't there a ne for "not equal"?

Answer (score 2):

Better to use a class for the rows.

Add a class for the rows that you want to wire double click event and it will be easier.